# How to get column values as a table column in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

This is my table defined in the database:

```
pi_value    | Status
------------+-------------------
    500.000 | Bank Submitted
   500.0000 | Bank Submitted
  1000.0000 | Maturity Received
  4000.0000 | Bank Submitted
    50.0000 | Maturity Received
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
Maturity Received | Bank Submitted | 
------------------+----------------+
       1050.0000  |    5000.0000   |
------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Sum, group by and pivot the results?

Comment: pivot in postgres?

Answer (score 1):

use conditional aggregation

```
  select sum(case when status='Bank Submitted' then pi_value else 0 end),
  sum(case when status='Maturity Received' then pi_value else 0 end) from table
```

Comment: Status are not fixed there are 15 more status and it is dynamic i have given some sample data

Answer (score 0):

As you say in a comment that the status is not before-known, just select the mere data and have your app or website do the layout:

```
select status, sum(pi_value) as total
from mytable
group by status
order by status;
```

Whatever programming language you are using, it will be easy to simply loop through the result set and fill some grid with it.

**Alternative:**

If you want to get the pivoted data right away, you'll have to use dynamic SQL instead. This means you select the data needed to build the query first, then you build the query from it and run it. Here is how to get the statuses:

```
select distinct status from mytable order by status;
```

Then loop through these and construct a query like shown in Zaynul Abadin Tuhin's answer. Then run that query.